# Accepted by European university, rejected by all American ones I applied to? Possible reasons?

Tags: phd, application

I've been wondering this for a while.

I'm currently doing the first year of my PhD in Frankfurt. Originally from New Zealand.

I'm not complaining about my situation but if anyone asks me I'll honestly say I would have preferred an English-speaking country.

I'd actually applied to about 9 PhD programs in the US and all rejected me. Yet I was accepted to a (supposedly far more competitive) fully funded European PhD, and rather quickly - accepted late last year and already working now.

It has me wonder. I had very strong letters of recommendation from professors that are well known in my field. I had also published a paper (which has now been cited in Nature) out of the fruits of my research Master's.

My GPA is about 2.8-2.9 by US standards (hard to convert, my school was a "we grade harshly, rarely give out As and we'll make you sweat for a B" style system). Professors at home told me my grades were irrelevant with the strong letters.

People say that I was likely discounted because I had a research master's already and I'd probably see doing more course load as beneath me? That doesn't seem to hold water.

I really don't know. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you include General and Subject GRE scores with the US applications? Even programs that say these are optional often put a lot of weight on them when making admissions decisions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect us to say. We don't know your CV, and your situation already clearly shows the (somewhat unsurprising) fact that different universities look for different things.

Comment: The programs I applied to said GRE was not just optional, but unnecessary, since I'm in a very young and interdisciplinary field. 

I guess it's troubling me because I'm worried that I only got the post on account of academic nepotism - current supervisor is a former student of my MS supervisor - even if the letters were anonymized before anyone saw them. Good old impostor effect.

Comment: 2.8-2.9 would easily get an American student rejected, perhaps without even reading the letters. If those grades are typical for NZ, I would expect the conversion formula would take this into account (otherwise no one from NZ would ever be accepted). but if your institution grades very harshly by NZ standards, that could easily explain it.

Comment: By the way, (I'm in the U.S., in mathematics) I know of no situation in which letters of recommendation are anonymized at all. And for better or for worse, "academic nepotism" is often decisive... Unclear whether or not it really means "inappropriate influence", or, perhaps, "detailed knowledge of the viewpoint of the letter writer".

Comment: The other thing that is really hard to say is what the relative "competitiveness" of the schools were that you applied to vs the ones you applied to in the US. It is not at all hard to get rejected from 9 institutions in the US, even if there is nothing wrong with your application - especially if these were 9 of the ones that have large international name recognition, simply because so very many people apply to them every year, especially internationally. Its a weird system.

Comment: Germany *is* an English-speaking country. U Frankfurt has a decent world ranking.

Comment: Looking up a 2.8 in my New Zealand institution's international GPA conversion guide, the equivalent local grades would be well below what we would consider for doctoral admission for domestic students. I don't know where you were, but it would have needed a lot of explanation even though we would certainly know the institution. Do you think that explanation was covered in your application materials or letters? What was the original GPA?

Comment: How is this question not going to be primarily opinion based? All any answer is going to do is speculate because there are a bunch of things we don't know about the OP, including the schools he applied to, test scores, possible grudges with his advisor, conference presentations, course-load, etc.

Comment: For the record, this is very similar to my (also anecdotal) experience. I'm Brazilian and applied to 4 American and 3 European MBA's. I didn't even get called for an interview by any of the Americans, but was accepted by all the Europeans (some of which were higher-ranked than the Americans). I just assumed there's some difference in the desired student profile on each side of the Atlantic.

Comment: 2.8 is a downright *terrible* GPA in the US. Really, anything under a 3.5 is not going to look good. Maybe you converted wrong? If not, then that's probably why. GPA might matter more in the US than in other countries.

Comment: Funds available to cover tuition, fees and provide a stipend may be available only to US citizens. I know that on doctoral admissions committees one of the things we consider is how students will be funded. I would also note that grads are *very much considered* (along with letters of recommendation): we take a broad look at grades, curriculum, test scores, publications, recommendations, the resume, and the personal statement. That said: congratulations!

Comment: What level of universities did you apply to in the US? Top tier schools would almost certainly reject the application based on the B– GPA without bothering to look at the recommendations, as cag51 says. Mid-to-lower tier programs _might_ look at them, but I suspect the recommendations alone would not be enough to counter the grades, so unless you have (near) perfect GREs I wouldn't expect you'd get into those either.

Comment: Anecdotally I've been told that recommendation letters targeted to US institutions need to be much more glowing than the ones targeted to European institutions to have the same effect. I don't know if that makes a difference in this case.

Answer (score 28):

It is sometimes difficult for admissions committees to evaluate applicants coming from universities or university systems that they don't have direct experience with.  This is especially true if they also don't know your letter writers.  It can help to apply to universities where someone in the dept. has some connection to the country you're applying from.  Since someone at Frankfurt knew one of your letter writers, that person may be better informed about your letter writers, the quality of your school, and the meaning of your grades.

Answer (score 26):

Many Universities have GPA cut-offs where they don't look at applications below a particular GPA threshold. The cut-off is generally much lower than the average admitted applicant, but can still be quite high. Universities vary on this, some don't do it at all, some have strict transparent GPA requirements, and some do this in practice but don't say so in writing. Most programs that use these sorts of GPA cut-offs would probably have a cut-off of 3.0 (or even higher for elite institutions). So your application may have not even been read if your official GPA conversion translated to 2.8 - 2.9!

If you want to avoid getting your application thrown away before it is even looked at, one strategy is to contact a professor in the department that you want to work with. If you convince them that you would be a great student under their supervision they can often contact the admissions committee and ask them to look out for your application. In this scenario, you still might not get admitted, as the committee does usually have the final say, but your letters of reference will at least be looked at, and the professor at the university you are applying to can send the committee a note about how tough your university is and how well respected your letter writers are in your field.

Your friend's explanation about your research masters is almost certainly wrong. I doubt many programs would reject you just because you already had a research masters.

Comment: From my experience, a 3.0 might be even a low cutoff. I have seen higher (e.g. 3.3)

Comment: Grade inflation is real and damaging!

Comment: The grade cutoff was my first thought as well.  Even the company I work for has a 3.0 grade cutoff for new graduate hires, and I'd expect that to have much less restrictive requirements than an internationally well-known PhD program.

Comment: Also I presume submitting a GRE (with very high scores) is almost mandatory when you want to claim 'its not me, its my school grading harshly".

Comment: @bremen_matt usually 3.0 (or even as low as 2.7) is the type of official requirement that might be written on a University website. But you are right, in practice, the admission committee might operate using a much higher threshold, 3.3 or even as high as 3.5 would not be uncommon for the most elite programs.

Comment: To be fair to myself, my in-topic GPA is over 3.5. I was the only person in my class to land an A+ in the courses closest to my specialty.

I was dragged down by my very... interesting... decision to simultaneously minor in Physics and Mathematics.

It seems I made the erroneous decision of thinking my letters and my extremely high in-topic grades would speak louder than the other stuff.

Comment: @CountessIsolde Please note that your letters & high in topic grades would definitely speak louder than that stuff if your application was actually seen. But I doubt anyone even looked at your application. A 2.8 GPA at a US institution is worse than the average undergrad student (median undergrad has a GPA between 3 - 3.3). It is not uncommon for the best PhD programs to get 500 applications competing over only a few spots! No one is going to read 500 applications, they have to cull some in an automated way just to make their job manageable. I'm sorry you fell victim to this system.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing related master's does make a significant difference in most US schools. Somebody that already has a master's will usually skip coursework and go directly to research because the school cannot grant a second master's in the same or related field.

This means you bypass the stage where you're being a TA and taking classes and consequently, there's no opportunity for you to get to know professors and their labs. On the flip side, there is no period for groups to assess your work before they invite you in.

Practically, in the departments I've been in, this means a student with a master's needs to contact professors prior to application review and find a group that is willing to accept them. From that point, the application is a mere formality.

As you have found out, there is little chance if somebody goes through the normal application route. Those applications tend to get stuck in a pile that PIs don't read.

The strongest way to do this is having your existing professors send an e-mail, especially to somebody they have a working relationship with. In any case, good recommendations are required with research background. Courses and grades aren't really that important.

Comment: While perhaps true for some fields of study at some particular universities, this is simply not true in general. For example, in mathematics, you'd likely still take coursework even if you got a masters elsewhere. You might be able to take different classes though. And at my university, you were allowed to get a second masters in mathematics.

Comment: In other places, you do not TA while you are still taking courses (the first year or two) but rather after that (the last, say, 3 years).

Comment: Hmm, this certainly isn't true in the fields I'm familiar with.

Comment: @RichardHardy Some schools, including my current institution, incentivize TAing with classes. After somebody is done with classes and qualifies, the tuition drops to a lower level. Because TAing comes with a tuition waiver, it's best to do this early. (There's a minimum 1 course TA requirement, so this is $30k+ of guaranteed money, the difference is something approaching $10k after overhead)